# Ending threads in Android - Drastic problems

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview, forceclose

I'm still pretty confused as to when / how to end threads in my Surfaceview application and was hoping someone could explain.

Currently, I am using this code:

```
Log.v("Destroyed","Surface Destroyed");

preThread.setRunning(false);  
boolean retry = true;        
while (retry) {
    try {
        preThread.join();
        retry = false;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

The above code sits in my surfaceDestroyed method - firstly, is this correct?

In my surfaceCreated method I have the following code which should check to see if the thread still exists or has been stopped and if it's been stopped, then re-start it:

```
if (runthread==false){

if (preThread.getState()==Thread.State.TERMINATED){
    preThread = new MainThread(thisholder, thiscontext, thishandler);}
else {}
    preThread.setRunning(true);
    preThread.start();
    }
```

It seems to act really strange.  Here is what I get:

*) When I first install the game and run it, through my logging, it says that the thread already exists, If I then press the back key, surfaceDestroyed is run but when I go back into the activity, again it says that the thread already exists.

*)  If I press the home key, then surfaceDestroyed is run and when I go back into the activity it says that the thread was previously destroyed and starts a new one.

*) If I kill the activity using DDMS, surfaceDestroyed isn't run and when I go back into the activity it says that the thread already exists.

If I'm thinking straight, then the third scenario is the only one that seems to make sense.

I'm clearly doing something drastically wrong.  The main problem is this:

If I hit the home key during the game and then end the app via DDMS in Eclipse, restart the app and hit the back key twice in quick succession (once, to go back to the previous activity, then again to get back to the splash screen) - the app force-closes and I get a "Fatal exception: Thread 12" in logcat.  I have to assume this is because my thread is never ending and is trying to be-restarted?  I'm not sure.

I've been trying to figure this out for what seems like an age so I really hope someone can explain what I'm doing wrong!

Many thanks!

Edit.  Logcat output.

[image]

my Run() method:

```
    public void run(){

    //Main Loop

    while (runthread){

    Log.v("tracking","runthread is: "+runthread);                             //This should only be logged while this loop is running

        timestart = System.currentTimeMillis();                             //Get time at start of loop for FPS calc

        try{c=mySurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();                                 //Set Canvas to locked

            synchronized(mySurfaceHolder){


                if (c==null){Log.v("Stop","Canvas is null for some reason - exiting, "+c+" - see?!!!");}


                framesskipped = 0;                                              // resetting frames skipped
        doDraw(c);                                                      //Draw to the screen
        updateMenu();
        }
        }
        finally{
            if (c != null){

            mySurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);                     //Post canvas

            }
        }

        //work out timings

            timeend = System.currentTimeMillis();                       //get end time for current frame (for FPS) 
            frametime = timeend-timestart;                              //Set the frametime variable to the time the frame took to render & update (end time - start time)
            sleepfor = (int) (33-frametime);                            // this is the time that the thread will sleep for if <target time


            if (sleepfor>0){                                            // If the 'sleepfor' variable is >0 then set the thread to sleep for it's value (expressed in ms)

                try {
                    OptionsThread.sleep(sleepfor);                      //send thread to sleep for value of sleepfor (determined above).
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}                     //in case of exception
            }                                                           //close if statement


                while (sleepfor<0 && framesskipped<maxframesskipped){   //if sleepfor is < 0 (ie, frame took longer to render than target time and the maxframesskipped has not reached it's limit)
                    updateMenu();                                       //Update animation variables without rendering to the screen while these conditions are met 
                    sleepfor+=33;                                       //time to sleep plus the time frame took to render
                    framesskipped++;                                    //add one to framesskipped variable so this only skips a certain number of frames
                    }
                }
            }
```

New Logcat output showing nullPointerException and output of logging. runThread is never logged as false so I'm not sure how the line that logs canvas as null is reached!

[image]

Thanks

Edit:

OK, I've completely started from scratch and re-written the whole class- it's very much a stripped-down version of what I had before and here is the whole class:

```
    import android.content.res.Resources;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.Surface;
    import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
    import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class OptionsScreen extends SurfaceView implements
  SurfaceHolder.Callback {   

    //Create Variables

    private SurfaceHolder thisHolder;
    private Context thisContext;
    private Handler thisHandler;
    private preThread thread;
    private Bitmap background;
    private Resources res;
    private Context myContext;
    private Handler myHandler;


    private Canvas c;
    //      thisholder = getHolder();


    public OptionsScreen(Context context) {
    super(context);

    myContext=context;                                  //This is the context passed into this constructor (this)
    thisHolder = getHolder();                           //Get surface holder
    thisHandler=getHandler();                           //Get Handler
    thisContext = getContext();                         //Get context
    res=getResources();                                 //Get resource

    //add the callback surface holder
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    //make focusable
    setFocusable(true);
    //create new thread
    thread = new preThread(thisHolder, thisContext, thisHandler);
    //create bitmaps from resources
    background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.sky);
}

 @Override
 public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    Log.v("check","surfaceChanged run");

 }

 @Override
 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    Log.v("check","surfaceCreated run"+thread.getState());

    int height = this.getHeight();
    int width = this.getWidth();

    if(thread.getState()==Thread.State.TERMINATED){             //Has thread been stopped previously? could happen if the home key is pressed
        Log.v("check","Thread still exists!!!! - Starting a new one. "+thread.getState()); 
        thread = new preThread(thisHolder, thisContext, thisHandler);

    }

    thread.setRunning(true);
            thread.start();

    Log.v("check","Thread - "+thread.getState());

 }

 @Override
 public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

      Log.v("check","surfaceDestroyed run"+thread.getState());

      thread.setRunning(false);                     //Set to false to exit run() method

     boolean retry = true;                          //Shut off rendering thread
          while (retry) {
            try {
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // try again shutting down the thread

           }

          }

 }

 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
     Log.v("check","Surface Touched");
    Log.v("check","Thread - "+thread.getState());
     // System.exit(0);

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    // if (canvas!=null){

        canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, null);
        Log.v("Stop","Canvas is "+canvas);
     }
 }








 //*******************************************************************
 //**                           run loop                            **
 //*******************************************************************

protected class preThread extends Thread {

    private SurfaceHolder mySurfaceHolder;
    private Context myContext;

    public preThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder, Context context, Handler handler) {               //Constructor

        mySurfaceHolder=surfaceholder;
        myContext=context;
        res = myContext.getResources();


    }



         // flag
         private boolean running;
         public void setRunning(boolean running) {
          this.running = running;
         }

         @Override
         public void run() {

                      while (running) {

            try{c=mySurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();                                 

            synchronized(mySurfaceHolder){


                Log.v("check","Drawing!!");

        onDraw(c);                                                      

        }
        }
        finally{
            if (c != null){

            mySurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);                     

            }
        }





          }
         }
        }
}
```

Comment: You should post stack-trace of the crash.
Restarting the running thread will give only you an IllegalStateException, with a message that "thread already started".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threads are pretty difficult to manage, but after some hit and trial i think i have come up with a scheme which works correctly most of the time. 
To End a Thread

```
 if(m_hThread != null)
        {
            try 
            {
                m_bThread = false; // m_bThread is the while condition of the thread
                m_hThread.interrupt(); // incase the thread is in sleep
                m_Thread.join(); // This call blocks and waits for thread to end
                m_hThread = null;  

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

For re-creating thread

```
 if(m_hThread == null) 
     {   
         m_bThread = true; //while condition of thread
         StartNewThread(); 
     }
```

In your implementation, No need to retry Thread.join, either it will join in the first try or it will block until the thread joins. As for your cases only the first case seems to be weird, where you find the thread is already running, this can't possibly be true. Second and third make complete sense to me, and work like they should. When the user clicks Home button `surfaceDestroyed` is invoked and thread is Terminated.

thread continues as long as m_bThread is true,

```
 while(m_bThread) //b
    {
      // Continuous Thread operations...
    }
```

m_hThread is simply preThread in your code, and m_Thread is a also m_hThread just a typing mistake here.

Comment: +1 for "signaling" the thread to exit: threads (in general) should not be aborted, they need to "volunteer" to exit. In practice, the thread have to exit.

Comment: The tricky part is: what should you do if the thread is in a blocking wait? (e.g. reading from a socket, waiting for a connection...?) In that case, a boolean var is not sufficient, and Java does not have a select/waitformultiple. But there are plenty of questions on SO on how to deal with that

Comment: Yes, something like that can cause join to block everything, in this case the surfaceDestroyed would take some time to complete. And android may show force-close dialog in the mean time. But again Managing of thread isn't something that we can just do in one step, it should be pre-planned accordingly.

Comment: @rigy73, thank you, I've looked over your code, but I don't understand what m_bThread, m_hThread and m_Thread are - could you explain a bit more please? Thanks again

Comment: Thanks @rigy73, unfortunately, it didn't work, I get the same issue when I press Home/Back (95% of the time, occasionally it's OK!). Logcat says (after the thread error) that I have a nullPointerException. I've traced this to the canvas. I've put some logging in and sure enough, canvas is returned as null when it crashes, what I can't understand is why the run() method is still running when runThread has been set to false? If I put a log in, it outputs true until I hit back/home then stops logging which is what I would expect, but still seems to get to the line that logs the canvas state?! –

Comment: I've just realised that if I remove everything from my doDraw() method, and just leave it blank, then I can run it and hit back as many times as I like, but I can't get it to crash.  Anyone have any ideas?  This one's really got me confused! I thought it might be the OptionsThread.sleep(sleepfor); line but I removed that whole section and get the same results.... thank you

Comment: Hi, one last update, hoping someone has a suggestion.  I completely re-wrote and simplified the entire class(es) and I get exactly the same problem. If onDraw() is empty, it runs fine, however, if it try to use canvas in anyway, then is is caught as null and everything goes South in exactly the same way it did before.  You may notice things are slightly different this time, but I was just trying things in a different way, but not joy :-(  If I put the line in that checks canvas status against null (commented out at the moment in onDraw(); then it works fine.... anyone?! :-(  Thank you

Comment: Instead of surfacecreated you should try drawing in surfacechanged. And in case canvas is null simply restart the activity.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by draw in surfaceChanged I'm not calling onDraw() from from surfaceCreated. Why is the code giving me a nullPointerException, should the code in the run() method not prevent that happening?

Comment: I meant start the thread in surfaceChanged, but your problem was never threads, you have asked the wrong question here. The reason you are getting a null pointer exception is because you are getting a null canvas. Which happens if you start drawing before surfacecreated is called or drawing after surfacedestroyed. Just make sure you don't do anything in onDraw before surfaceCreated and after surfacedestroyed atleast until surfacecreated is called again.

Comment: And remember just because you signaled thread to end, does not mean it has ended. It may just have passed another condition check cycle and will complete at least one iteration, during which it will call ondraw on a empty canvas, hence a null pointer. So handle the null pointer case in your canvas, and only draw if you get a valid canvas.

Comment: I know I realise now I've asked the wrong question, you say "Just make sure you don't do anything in onDraw before surfaceCreated and after surfacedestroyed", but I'm not sure how to do that, is my 'check for null' within onDraw acceptable?  I have accepted your answer and awarded the bounty. You've been very helpful and I thank you, if you could just confirm my last questions here I would be very grateful.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Yes it is acceptable, you can put up a pretty large no of checks before running into any performance issues.